# How to change the name of Android application

Tags: android

I started with an application in Android with a silly name. I didn't figure it out that it should have a proper name. And now I want it to be changed over the entire application.
I am not sure how can I achieve this in Eclipse. Should I just copy paste the new name in entire application or is there a second possibility which might be easy?

Stone

Comment: What do you mean by application name ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3462431/how-to-name-android-application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just change in your res/value/string.

```
<string name="app_name">put appropriate name</string>
```

if not work then android menifest

```
< activity android:name="< app name>" android:label="< >" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
```

try its works.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Application tag which should be changed? What you suggest will only change Activity name I guess.

Comment: according to que. application name will be changed i whole apllication.

Comment: Sitanshu is right .. change the app_name in Androidmanifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you just need to change attribute `android:label` in `AndroidManifest.xml` for the **Application** tag.

Answer (score 0):

change the app name in String.xml file

like `<string name="app_name">MyAppname</string>`

it will automaticlly changed in menifest file